# Use node_modules of parent directory in child projects

Tags: webpack, node-modules, bootstrap-sass

I have one master project, with little projects inside, and I want to use node_modules of the main project on the little ones, for don' generate extra folders with the same node_modules.

I want to use SASS, bootstrap and jquery in my HTML/PHP projects.

I did a basic configuration on webpack. I required jquery and bootstrap. But I think I need to configure the loaders to.

```
MAIN PROJECT
    -assets/
    -node_modules/
    -index.php
    -package.json
    -webpack.config.js

    -PROJECT.1
        -assets/
        -node_modules/
        -package.json
        -index.php
    -PROJECT.2
        -assets/
        -node_modules/
        -package.json
        -index.php
    -PROJECT.3
        -assets/
        -node_modules/
        -package.json
        -index.php
```

Comment: You shouldn't do anything special. `require` and `import` will automatically search in the parent's `node_modules` if they don't find the module in the children. Did you try it?

Comment: I config the webpack now and I install the bootstrap jquery and stuff, and I did it the require in the main project JS file, but how I use it in the child projects ?